# Does android supports SVG or Tiny SVG?

Tags: android-layout

does android supports SVG or Tiny SVG ? I am having doubt like if i want to publish my application to android market which will cover different sizes of android devices then in that case i need to create same images with different densities, sizes etc.. and need to put on the different folders as specified in android developer guides. I just want to avoid it because it will unnecessarily increase the apk file size so rather than using this approach can we create the vector graphics file and store all image related information and add it in to the apk file.
but I am not able to find whether vector graphics approach will work in android or not and if it is working then how to use it?
Please provide me some valuable information about it.

Regards,
Piks

Answer (score 0):

I found [TinyLine](http://www.tinyline.com/svgt/index.html). I have not tried it, but it seems to be sophisticated.